# Convert flashes to array as standard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am starting to learn ruby on rails, like it so far. But I have a hard time wrapping my head around those flash-sessions.

I would rather have it working something like:

```
flash[:alert] << "first alert message" 
flash[:alert] << "second alert message"
```

But, it doesn't work (edit: since flash[:alert] isn't an array). A solution would be to initiate flash[:alert] as an empty array in some kind of construct, i tried it in a before_filter but didn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Edit:
As I've written in some comments. What i am trying to do is find a place to convert flash[:alert] to an array. In some sort of construct. If i do it before i call flash[:alert] i have to know when i will be doing it the first time so i won't overwrite anything I allready have in it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Having two messages?

Comment: "But, it doesn't work." - No valid error description.

Comment: Tass: Nope, terribly bad error description. What I am after is some place to convert the flash[:alert] to an array. An construct of some sort. I tried it in before_filter as stated, but it didn't get called before I added a flash to the alert.

lucapette: I am trying to have the flash[:alert] (or any other flash) behave as an array (or hash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper method in your application controller. For example, like this:

```
class ApplicationController

  def add_to_flash_array key, value
    # set empty array as default value
    flash[key] ||= [] 

    if flash[key].is_a? Array
      flash[key] << value
    else # somebody set a value from underneath this method, enter panic mode
      raise "flash['#{key}'] is not an array!"
    end
  end
end

# usage

add_to_flash_array :alert, 'Message 1'
add_to_flash_array :alert, 'Message 2'
```

Then in your view loop over `flash[:alert]` and build your markup.

Answer (score 2):

As @lucapette asked, what are you trying to do? If you want multiple messages on multiple lines, you can explicitly add new lines:

```
flash[:alert] += "\nSecond message."
```

Or you should be able to do something like this:

```
flash[:alert] = []
flash[:alert] << "Message 1"
```

And then when you can modify your application layout to loop through the flashes, assuming they will *always* be Arrays. If they will only sometimes be an array, you can check that first with something like:

```
flash[:alert].class == Array
```

or

```
flash[:alert].is_a? Array
```

or automatically make it an array anyways:

```
Array(flash[:error])
```

Then you can loop around it any way you want.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

But i wan't to convert the flash[:error] to an array allways, else i must know where i send my first flash and convert it to an array there. So therefore i am looking for a construct of sorts to put the code Array(flash[:error]) in.